# Deploying a VS SharePoint solution to the "Web Application"

Tags: web-application, gac

When deploying a VS SharePoint solution to the "Web Application", where does the actual assembly go?

I mistakenly switched the Assembly Deployment Target of several of my projects to "Web Application" thinking it might be less trouble (as DLLs in the GAC often get locked), however I realized afterwards they need to be in the GAC to work. Now, when I try and deploy them back to the GAC and activate the features I get the lovely "Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Failed to load receiver assembly" error.

As such, I'm thinking maybe there are copies of the DLLs sitting wherever "Web Application" installation puts them that I need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The dll goes to bin folder of web app.

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories{yourWebApp}\bin